# Is there any connection between the central angle and the exterior angle of a hexagon

Tags: trigonometry

The central angle of a regular polygon is formed by two lines from consecutive vertices to the centre point or two radii of consecutive vertices of the circumsribed circle.

I can plot each point on the hexagon by using the same length of radii and rotating $60$ degrees from the center.

I know I can work out the exterior angle by $(n−2) \cdot 180^\circ$.

That gives me $720 / 6 = 120$, and $180 - 120 = 60$.

Is there any connection between the central angle and the exterior angle?

Comment: When plotting a hexagon... I draw the vertices and then drawn the lines between them.  I personally never "rotate" anything... so what do you mean by "rotating" here?

Comment: I mean each central angle is 60 degrees.

Comment: just curious why the external angle and central angle are the same

Comment: If you were to center your hexagon on the origin and you draw rays from the origin to each of the vertices... are you asking why the angle between rays is $60^\circ$?  That is simply because $\frac{360^\circ}{6}=60^\circ$...  We have $360^\circ$ total in the center and we divided it up into six parts since there are six vertices.  No deeper meaning behind it than that.

Comment: so there is no connection with the exterior angle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an answer to your question on comments, notice that when we draw a line from a vertex to center of a regular polygon, that line is angle bisector of an interior angle, say interior angle is $2\alpha$. In a triangle constructed this way, there are two such $\alpha$ angles, so central angle is $180 - 2\alpha$. But notice that this is as same as the exterior angle. Therefore this is not special to hexagon. Here is a sketch for a general result:

[image: sketch]

Answer (score 1):

For a regular $n$-gon the central angle is $\frac {360}n$.

The central angles cut the $n$-gon into $n$ isoceles triangles.  So that base of  these triangles are $\frac {180 - \frac {360}n}2 = 90 - \frac{180}n$.  The interior angles are two of these base angles so the interior angles $180 - \frac {360}n$.

And there for the exterior angles are $180 - (180 - \frac {360}n) = \frac {360}n$.

So this is true no matter what regular $n$-gon you do.

Hexagons and $60$ degrees are particularly important number as represent the sides and radius being equal and tesselates the plane.